# Flag counter in the 10k tools shows flags but I don't see them

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, flags

I am seeing on the [Tools](https://android.stackexchange.com/tools) page that there are flags but there aren't any flags.

[image: screen shot]

As you can see, there is a number next to "flags" in addition to the incorrect count in the right column. There are no flags to handle.

Refreshing didn't help. Nor did going to another page and returning.

This has been happening since at least the revamp to the Closing system.

Comment: I see 5 moderator flags right now. So they are there and it seems that they are just not shown to you for some reason.

Comment: @Flow I wonder if it's an issue with previously being a moderator?

Comment: @Bryan: I don't think so. It didn't used to do that.

Comment: @BryanDenny No, it isn't. I've seen that a lot recently as well, and I never was mod. Most times the number initially corresponded to the flags shown, and just seemed not to be updated when I had processed them. Maybe Al can approve this context ("not updated after being processed")?

Comment: I seem to recall seeing something like this quite a while ago, it may still be a caching issue.